# Why my Runge kutta code is not working correctly?

Tags: matlab

Below is my code for a 4th order Runge-Kutta but I keep getting a wrong answer and I don't see what is the problem with the code. I was hoping somebody could help point me in the right direction to fix my code.

```
function [Theta,r]=test3rk4(m,k,l_0,R1,A1,R2,A2,h,t_end)
t=0:h:t_end;
% A1 = zeros(1,numel(t)) % A2 = A1; R1 = A1; R2 = A1;
% R1 = zeros(1,numel(t))
g=9.81;
f1=@(A2) A2;
f2=@(A1,A2,R1,R2) -2*(R2./R1).*A2-g*sin(A1);
f3=@(R2) R2;
f4=@(A1,A2,R1) R1.*(A2.*A2)+g*cos(A1)-k*(R1-l_0)/m;
for i=1:(length(t)-1)
k11=h*f1(A2(i));
k12=h*f2(A1(i),A2(i),R1(i),R2(i));
k13=h*f3(R2(i));
k14=h*f4(A1(i),A2(i),R1(i));
 
k21=h*f1((A2(i)+k12/2));
k22=h*f2((A1(i)+k11/2),(A2(i)+k12/2),(R1(i)+k13/2),(R2(i)+k14/2));
k23=h*f3((R2(i)+k14/2));
k24=h*f4((A1(i)+k11/2),(A2(i)+k12/2),(R1(i)+k13/2));

k31=h*f1((A2(i)+k22/2));
k32=h*f2((A1(i)+k21/2),(A2(i)+k22/2),(R1(i)+k23/2),(R2(i)+k24/2));
k33=h*f3((R2(i)+k24/2));
k34=h*f4((A1(i)+k21/2),(A2(i)+k22/2),(R1(i)+k23/2));
  
k41=h*f1((A2(i)+k32));
k42=h*f2((A1(i)),(A2(i)+k32),(R1(i)+k33),(R2(i)+k34));
k43=h*f3((R2(i)+k34));
k44=h*f4((A1(i)),(A2(i)+k32),(R1(i)+k33));
 
A1(i+1) = A1(i) + (k11+2*k21+2*k31+k41)/6;
A2(i+1) = A2(i) + (k12+2*k22+2*k32+k42)/6;
R1(i+1) = R1(i) + (k13+2*k23+2*k33+k43)/6;
R2(i+1) = R2(i) + (k14+2*k24+2*k34+k44)/6;
end
Theta=A1;
r=R1;
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(t,A1,'LineWidth',1)
title('theta vs t')
xlabel('t','fontsize',14,'fontweight','bold')
ylabel('Theta','fontsize',14,'fontweight','bold')
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(t,R1,'LineWidth',1)
xlabel('t','fontsize',14,'fontweight','bold')
ylabel('r','fontsize',14,'fontweight','bold')
subplot(2,2,[3,4])
x=R1.*sin(A1)
y=-R1.*cos(A1)
plot(x,y)
end
```

Comment: My RK4 is here: https://github.com/sjhalayka/mercury_orbit_glut/blob/54dd9f93b6f8a7c4dd808d8cc42e93f3055d8ec6/main.cpp#L46

Comment: could you throw your math problem statement? with initial values for each function? I see issues when you finding the values recursively - i.e. your functions are f1 f2 f3 f4 but you're finding A1 A2 R1 R2. try CTRL+C -> CTRL+V formula from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge–Kutta_methods

Comment: yes, I called A1=theta so A2=dtheta, R1=r, and R2= dr.
my initial condision : dr/dt=0, dtheta/dt=0, theta=pi/6, r=10.
The input : (71,1000,8,10,pi/6,0,0,1,10)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are missing code in your k42 and k44 calculations. You have this:

```
k42=h*f2((A1(i)),(A2(i)+k32),(R1(i)+k33),(R2(i)+k34));
:
k44=h*f4((A1(i)),(A2(i)+k32),(R1(i)+k33));
```

But it looks like you need this instead for the A1 parts:

```
k42=h*f2((A1(i)+k31),(A2(i)+k32),(R1(i)+k33),(R2(i)+k34));
:
k44=h*f4((A1(i)+k31),(A2(i)+k32),(R1(i)+k33));
```

Also it would help if you posted the differential equations you are solving so that we could check the f1, f2, f3, and f4 function handles.

And it looks like you are passing in an h=1 value for the step size. This is *way* too big for what looks like some type of pendulum problem. You should drop that to something like 0.01 or so.

Finally, in the future it would help if you vectorized your differential equation code. This means making a function handle that takes in a 4-element state vector and outputs a 4-element derivative vector. That way your RK4 code only has one set of vectorized equations instead of four separate sets of scalar equations like you currently have. It also makes it easy to check your code against the built-in ode45( ) function because you can use the same derivative function.